# ViewBinding.getRoot().getLayoutParams() always return null

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

When I use ViewBinding in my RecyclerView.Adapter like that:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val itemView1 = MyItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).root
    val itemView2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false)
    val itemView3 = MyItemBinding.bind(itemView2).root
    return ViewHolder(itemView1)
}
```

The `itemView1`'s layoutParams is always null -- ignore attrs in xml, and `itemView2`&`itemView3`'s layoutParams works normally.
So does this is a bug for ViewBinding::inflate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Layout params come from the parent layout, and if you inflate without a parent, there won't be layout params. Use the overload that takes a parent layout:

```
val itemView1 = MyItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false).root
```

(Would be a good idea to also capture the binding reference and not throw it away immediately, too.)